# how to get image resolution from url in golang

Tags: go

How to get the resolution of an image from a URL in golang.

Below is the code i am trying.

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://i.imgur.com/Peq1U1u.jpg")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

m, _, err := image.Decode(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
g := m.Bounds()
fmt.Printf(g.String())
```

Can you guys tell me how to get the resolution in above situation

Comment: what's your Decode error? If you have the image, isn't this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're almost there. Your `g` variable is of the `image.Rectangle` type, which has the `Dx()` and `Dy()` methods, which give width and height respectively. We can use these to compute the resolution.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    _ "image/gif"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    _ "image/png"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://i.imgur.com/Peq1U1u.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    m, _, err := image.Decode(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    g := m.Bounds()

    // Get height and width
    height := g.Dy()
    width := g.Dx()

    // The resolution is height x width
    resolution := height * width

    // Print results
    fmt.Println(resolution, "pixels")
}
```

Comment: an image.Rectangle has Dx() and Dy() so you don't need to calculate it.

Comment: Right you are @JimB, I'll update the answer with that.

Comment: How if I want to get mime type?

Answer (score 3):

**`image.Decode` decodes the entire image, use `image.DecodeConfig` instead to parse only the image header:**

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://i.imgur.com/Peq1U1u.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        return // handle error somehow
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    img, _, err := image.DecodeConfig(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return // handle error somehow
    }

    fmt.Println(img.Width * img.Height, "pixels")
}
```